# Reschedule German visa appointment

Tags: bookings, schengen-visas

I have scheduled an appointment at German consulate Bangalore via https://service2.diplo.de. May I know how can I reschedule my appointment?

If I found an earlier slot available how can I change my appointment to that date? Should I cancel my current appointment first and then need to book a new one or shall I edit and reschedule my current appointment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change your appointment yourself online, so I'd suggest [calling them](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/vertretungen/generalkonsulat1) under +91 80 45 30 01 00 (note that they only take visa questions from Monday to Thursday, 14:00-15:30) or using this [contact form](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/vertretungen/generalkonsulat1/kontakt-formular-gk1). Don't cancel your current appointment until you've got the new one.